# Use wp_nav_menu in log in/log out menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I've added a log in/log out item to my menu, and I'd like to add a WordPress menu as a submenu to the log in item, but it's not working as intended.

```
function add_log_in_out_links( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary-menu') {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $items .= '<li class=""><a href="#">' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name . '</a>' . wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'sub-menu' ) ) . '</li>';
    }

    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary-menu') {
        $items .= '<li class=""><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Log In</a></li>';
    }

    return $items;
}
```

With this code, the wp_nav_menu(), which is wrapped with `<ul>` is jumping outside the parent `<li>`. See image -
[image: WordPress menu oustide of <li> tag]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_nav_menu() defaults to echo. This was happening before my $items variable was returned, so I turned wp_nav_menu() to return rather than echo.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/